# Reattach a component to a different parent

Tags: reactjs

I need to reattach a component to a different parent programmatically.

Let's say the parent of a `div` is a `h1` element. If some button is pressed then this `div` should be detached and reattached to the `body` element directly.

How should I handle this in react.js? The component (the `div` in the above example) where I need this feature is part of a 3rd party library, so I don't have a way to influence where the user puts this component in the first place.

Comment: Why don't you have a way to influence where the user puts the component? Or is the `div` within the 3rd party component (not top-level)?

Comment: The component that I develop is a widget that is part of a library that other users can use and add where they want on their site. The widget should have the feature that it can be undocked and then can be moved around freely (like a window in a desktop environment). For that to work it must be detached and reattached to the body element (or the top React element).